# Не работает определение местоположения на API 23

Tags: android, google-maps-api, геолокация

Вот код для определения местоположения:

```
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return;
    }
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(googleApiClient, locationRequest, new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {;
            zoom = 17;
            myCoord = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());

            if (myPos != null)
                myPos.remove();

            myPos = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(myCoord));
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(myCoord, zoom));
            Log.i("speech", "Changed at first");
            googleApiClient.disconnect();
        }

    });
```

На 5.1(22) работает без каких-либо изъянов. На 23 нет. Тестил на HUAWEI Honor 6.

```
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, 1);
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1);
        return;
    }
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(googleApiClient, locationRequest, new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {;
            zoom = 17;
            myCoord = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());

            if (myPos != null)
                myPos.remove();

            myPos = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(myCoord));
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(myCoord, zoom));
            Log.i("speech", "Changed at first");
            googleApiClient.disconnect();
        }

    });


private GoogleMap mMap = null;
private LatLng myCoord = null;
private Marker myPos;
private int zoom;

private TextView speedView;
private int speed = 0;

private GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;
private LocationRequest locationRequest;

private LocationManager locationManager;

Button danFaggot;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.v("ok", "onCreate started");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    Speech.init(this, getPackageName());

    speedView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.speedView);
    speedView.setText(String.valueOf(speed) + " " + "km/h");

    danFaggot = (Button) findViewById(R.id.danFaggot);
    danFaggot.setOnClickListener(this);

    googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getApplicationContext())
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .build();

    locationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    locationRequest.setInterval(1);
    locationRequest.setFastestInterval(1);
    locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);

    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);



}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    Log.v("ok", "onMapReady started");
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    googleApiClient.connect();
    Log.v("ok", "onStart started");
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    Log.v("ok", "onPause started");
    locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    Log.v("ok", "onStop started");
    googleApiClient.disconnect();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.v("ok", "onDestroy started");
    locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);
}

@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
    requestLocationUpdates();
    Log.v("ok", "onConnected started");
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {}
@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {}

void requestLocationUpdates() {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, 1);
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1);
        return;
    }
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(googleApiClient, locationRequest, new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {;
            zoom = 17;
            myCoord = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());

            if (myPos != null)
                myPos.remove();

            myPos = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(myCoord));
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(myCoord, zoom));
            Log.i("speech", "Changed at first");
            googleApiClient.disconnect();
        }

    });

    boolean IS_NETWORK_POVIDER_ENABLED = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
    boolean IS_GPS_PROVIDER_ENABLED = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

    if (IS_GPS_PROVIDER_ENABLED){
        Log.i("speech", "GPS enabled");
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, 2);
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 3);
            return;
        }
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1, 1, locationListener);
    }

    if (IS_NETWORK_POVIDER_ENABLED) {
        Log.i("speech", "NETWORK enabled");
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, 4);
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 5);
            return;
        }
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 1, 1, locationListener);
    }
}


android.location.LocationListener locationListener = new android.location.LocationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        Log.i("speech", "Changed");
        LatLng newMyCoord = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());

        if (myPos != null)
            myPos.remove();
        myPos = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(newMyCoord));
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(newMyCoord, zoom));

        speed = (int) (location.getSpeed()*3600) / 1000;
        speedView.setText(String.valueOf(speed) + " " + "km/h");
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

    }
};





 void requestLocationUpdates() {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, 1);
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1);
        return;
    }else {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(googleApiClient, locationRequest, new LocationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {;
                zoom = 17;
                myCoord = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());

                if (myPos != null)
                    myPos.remove();
                myPos = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(myCoord));
                mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(myCoord, zoom));
                Log.i("speech", "Changed at first");
                googleApiClient.disconnect();
            }

        });
    }

    boolean IS_NETWORK_POVIDER_ENABLED = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
    boolean IS_GPS_PROVIDER_ENABLED = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

    if (IS_GPS_PROVIDER_ENABLED){
        Log.i("speech", "GPS enabled");
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, 2);
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 3);
            return;
        }else {
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1, 1, locationListener);
        }
    }

    if (IS_NETWORK_POVIDER_ENABLED) {
        Log.i("speech", "NETWORK enabled");
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, 4);
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 5);
            return;
        }else{
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 1, 1, locationListener);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: В коде у вас не запрошено разрешение в случае его отсутствия. Запросите его и согласитесь в роли юзера.

Comment: оно есть в манифесте. прописано. или я не про это?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Начиная с Android 6.0 (уровень API 23), пользователи предоставляют разрешения для приложений во время работы приложения, а не при установке приложения. 
Этот подход упрощает процесс установки приложения, поскольку пользователю не нужно предоставлять разрешения при установке или обновлении приложения. Он также дает пользователю больше контроля над функциональностью приложения.
Например, пользователь может выбрать доступ к камере, но не к местоположению устройства. Пользователь может отменить разрешения в любое время, перейдя на экран настроек приложения.

Системные разрешения делятся на две категории: нормальные и опасные:

Обычные разрешения напрямую не влияют на конфиденциальность пользователя. Если ваше приложение отображает нормальное разрешение в своем манифесте, система автоматически предоставляет разрешение.

Опасные разрешения могут предоставить приложению доступ к конфиденциальным данным пользователя. Если ваше приложение отображает нормальное разрешение в своем манифесте, система автоматически предоставляет разрешение. Если вы указываете опасное разрешение, пользователь должен явно предоставить одобрение вашему приложению. Как в вашем случае.

Пример из оф. доков:

```
// thisActivity это ваша текущая операция
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity, Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)
        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

    // Показывать ли объяснение?
    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(thisActivity,
            Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)) {

    } else {

       // Никаких объяснений не требуется, мы можем запросить разрешение.

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(thisActivity,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS},
                MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);
    }
}
```

Для вашего случая пример будет примерно такой, как Юрий написал:

```
private static final int MY_LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST = 45;

if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    //--> выводит диалог, где пользователю предоставляется выбор
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, MY_LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST);
}else{
    //--> продолжаем работу или вызываем метод или класс
}
```

Comment: а чему должа быть равна переменная MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS?

Comment: так сделал?
обновил вопрос.

Comment: это ваш request флаг, он отлавливается в колбеке onRequestPermissionsResult, вне зависимости какое было поведение пользователя, те вы показали диалог с MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS = 45 к примеру, после пользователь отменил его и в колбек приходит state - requestCode = 45. и вы понимаете что это запрос на контакты, также можете проверить результат и напомнить например пользователя что без этого разрешения ничего например не будет работать) Любая логика.

Comment: обновил. все правильно?

Comment: да всё верно, сейчас для вашего случая лично добавлю, если хотите

Comment: что добавите???

Comment: вот внизу у меня или у Юрия скопируйте, код он именно для вашего случая

Comment: ок. а вот у меня несколько раз идет это проверка на разрешение. два метода. это один из них - для определения местоположения при старте.
а следующий раз когда locationListener вешаю. для трэкинга.
я полный код залил.

Comment: так вот. пермишен ID можно один и тот же использовать или разный должен быть?

Comment: разный, чтоб можно было определить какой

Comment: а вот код который у меня после проверки идет(определение местоположения) не нужно в else запихнуть?

Comment: да, как в примере обязательно иначе не в зависимости от разрешения будет вызывать и тогда вы словите SecurityException

типо такого java.lang.SecurityException: "gps" location provider requires ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission. 

Кстати для работы достаточно FINE_LOCATION, там знание LocationProvider требуется как они в паре работают, но достаточного FINE

Comment: так? обновил вопрос. внизу метод один закинул

Comment: правильно все сделал?

Comment: Немного тяжело читать код, все в одном месте. Внизу то что будет работать, но флагов в вашем случае 2 должно быть. Один для Coarse другой для FINE , просто выберите блок какой нить поменьше, протестируйте его на работоспособность. Вынести проверку в отдельный метод, чтоб класс не раздувался, потом же сами запутаетесь

Comment: ок спасибо за помощб

Answer (score 2):

C 6 версии андроида многие разрешения надо запрашивать программно, прописывания их в манифесте не достаточно.

Вам надо в случае отсутствия разрешения запросить его так:

```
private static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST = 1;

if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    //выводит диалог, где пользователю предоставляется выбор
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, PERMISSION_REQUEST);
}else{
    //продолжаем работу или вызываем метод или класс
}
```

Comment: а чему должа быть равна переменная PERMISSION_REQUEST?

Comment: @PavelVorobyov, любому числу. Это просто ID для колбэка изменения разрешений. В моём ответе это, например, `1`

Comment: там только реквест Юрий на камеру стоит ;)

Comment: @ShwarzAndrei, действительно) Исправил)